# play livestreaming video from rtsp link on mozilla and chrome browsers

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, rtsp

In my web application am able to display the video from rtsp link on mozilla browser but not able to display  on chrome. Please suggest me to solve this problem.

this is my code

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab"  events="True">
            <param name="Src" value="rtsp://cameraipaddress" />
             <param name="ShowDisplay" value="True" />
             <param name="AutoLoop" value="False" />    
             <param name="AutoPlay" value="True" />
            <embed type="application/x-google-vlc-plugin"  windowless="true" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" autoplay="yes" loop="no" width="100%" height="100%" src="rtsp://admin:admin@x.x.x.x:111/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0&unicast=true&proto=Onvif" ></embed>
             </OBJECT>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you have a problem with your code, then let us know a few of the things you tried already which didn't work. Then maybe we can help from there.

Comment: In Chrome NPAPI plugins like Vlc Web Plugin doesn't work. Vlc people is planning to port it to PPAPI but currently there is no info about schedule.

Comment: Okay..!!! but one more thing i tried, converting rtsp to webrtc online. By doing this it worked for me on both browsers. I converted on one website known as (http://www.live555.com/). @Michael Fourre